# How do I make a Selection Menu that collects users from a server in discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I wanted to make a Menu to select users from the server (Bot Style Nekotina#0608), to implement in a userinfo command, but I don't know how to do it, can you help me?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hH8Ax.png)

I tried the normal ActionRow way, but i wanted it to look like the image above...

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built in [UserSelectMenuBuilder](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/14.7.1/class/UserSelectMenuBuilder) for the Select Menu based upon Users. You must use the latest discord.js version, 14.7.1. You can build it like so:

```js
// Imports
const Discord = require('discord.js');



// Your handler {


const UserSelectMenu = new Discord.UserSelectMenuBuilder()
.setCustomId('user-menu')
.setMaxValues(1) // One user maximum
.setMinValues(1) // One user minimum
.setPlaceHolder('Select one User');
    
// Create an action row

const row = new Discord.ActionRowBuilder()
.setComponents(UserSelectMenu); // Select menus take up the whole row, so make sure there is a row for each select menu.

// Send the message

interaction.reply({ content: 'Choose a user' components: [row]});

// } End of handler
```

Hope this helps